set up plugin to run one at a time
i have a plugin at the Create step of an entity. This plugin performs a fetch query and updates a record. The plugin has about 5 simultaneous executions. I need the second execution to only start when the first one finishes, and so on. I need this so that the first execution has time to update the record, and then the fetch in the second execution does not find this updated record
i've already tried using Sleep, Mutex and SemaphoreSlim

Please explain, do is this plugin triggered by 5 concurrent create requests? If so, what is the source of these requests and is it possible to intercept and synchronize them there?

@HenkvanBoeijen it's a power automate workflow that runs every day at a specific time. This workflow calls an action, which retrieves some banking information and creates some records. These created records are the trigger for the plugin at the Create step that I mentioned in the post. Typically, around 5 records are created every day, but this number can vary

So why not handle it all in this flow or handle all work in the action?

If I were doing this, I would forgo the plugin and write a console application that utilizes the CRM SDK.  I don't know if you are using Online or On Premise.  I work  with On Premise and don't know if console applications are available to Online users.  If you can, it would allow you to handle everything in one place from creating the 5 records to processing the records afterwards with the plugin code.
